# Code completion in WebStorm just like ReSharper for Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, resharper, webstorm

I'm used to use Visual Studio as my IDE however I'd like to give WebStorm a go.

One feature that is really handy in Visual Studio (using ReSharper) when coding in JavaScript is that it creates the whole block for `function` or `for loops for you. In WebStorms it seems that only the "function" word is auto completed for you.

In VS and ReSharper, I'm able to type `fun` then press TAB and the following statement is added for me

```
function () {
    //CURSOR stops here
}
```

in WebStorm, if I type `fun` and choose the auto completion, only the word `function` is auto completed for me.

The same for for loops. In VS+ ReSharper, I can type `for` and press TAB and the following statement is added for me:

```
for (var i; i <= LENGTH; i++) {

}
```

QUESTION: Is there a way to get WebStorms to auto create these sort of code statements for us just like ReSharper does?

ReSharper is from the JetBrains just like WebStorms so I'm not sure this is not standard.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found it!

In WebStorms, it's called [Live Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/live-templates-2.html) and it's very... very customizable. Great IDE!